# Message parsing system in Python

Tags: python, function, dynamic, input, message

I'm constantly receiving serial input and am storing the messages I receive in a queue.

I want to parse the messages in this queue and do different things with them.

For example, if I receive the message "KEY0" I want to call my function Key0().

If I receive the message "LOGXrandom message" I want to write 'random message' to a file logx.txt, or logy.txt if the message is "LOGYrandom message".

What is the best way to create a system that would do something like this?

Answer (score 0):

isn't that pretty trivial,

- subscribe to message received event from your queue
- extract the command
- use switch cases

Did I understand the question  correctly ?

Comment: I realize it is trivial. I wouldn't be asking if I personally felt it was trivial, and I don't understand what you meant by any of that.

Comment: I can't be any clear than what I wrote, what were you expecting ?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by 'subscribe to message received event'. What does that mean?

I don't know what you mean by 'extract the command'.

Can you provide an example of those in use?

Comment: To answer those questions one would need to know which queue are you using,every queue throws an event when a message arrives in it,one has to subscribe to it to revive the payload, then from the payload which is perhaps a string, you would need to parse the command, then based on those commands you need to use a switch case statement to choose appropriate method or task to perform which could be logging or calling another method. If you want ore then you need to describe what you have tried so far and whats troubling you

Comment: I am asking what you even mean by 'subscribing' and 'extracting'. I have never heard that used before. Do you not understand what I mean by this?

Comment: That's essentially what I've done.

What about a parsing mechanism?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming module 'keys' with method 'key0':

```
import keys
methodToCall = getattr(keys, 'key0')
result = methodToCall()
```

As far as that goes lines 2 and three can be compressed to:

```
result = getattr(keys, 'key0')()
```